# Controlling Input Field Focus With React State and UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a very basic form where I am attempting to control the focus and blur of an input element using state and useEffect. Selecting and deselecting the input via mouse works just fine, but I also have a button that should toggle the focus on/off which is not working properly. When you press the button, the focus never toggles off for some reason.

I must be missing something simple here, but this is driving me crazy. Here is the code below, and a [link to a working codepen](https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/mdmJWEX?editors=0010).

```
const Focus = () => {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(true)
  const inputRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (focused) {
      inputRef.current.focus()
    } else {
      inputRef.current.blur()
    }
  }, [focused])

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type="text"
        onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
        onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setFocused(!focused)}>Toggle Focus</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Inputs have an `autofocus` attribute, just use that.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. I want to be able to use the button to toggle focus on and off at my choosing. The only thing not working is the button. It's doing something weird, which I am embarrassed I cannot find.

Answer (score 3):

Commenting off the onBlurHandler solves the issue

```
 // onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
```

when you are calling the setFocused(!focused) then the useEffect is triggered which in turn triggers the onBlur and unnecessarily tries to call setFocus again. That creates an infinite loop of some sort. So just remove that unnecessary onBlur from input because it's not serving any purpose

```
const Focus = () => {
  const [focused, setFocused] = React.useState(true);
  const inputRef = React.useRef();


  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('current ' , focused)
    if (focused) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    } else {
      inputRef.current.blur();
    }
  }, [focused]);
  
  const toggleFocus = () => {
    setFocused(prev => !prev)
  }
  
  const unFocus = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
            if (focused) setFocused(false)
        }, 300);
  }
  
  const focus =() => {
    if(!focused)setFocused(true)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type="text"
        onBlur={unFocus}
        onFocus={focus}
      />
      <button onClick={toggleFocus}>Toggle Focus</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Focus />, document.querySelector('.app'))
```

The following code solves the issue. I am not sure what is the exact problem but most probably it's the race condition which is handled internally by react

Comment: There isn't an infinite loop, I'm checking in the console how many times the component re-renders. Also, with your solution that causes another bug now.

Comment: can I know what that bug is?

Comment: If you go to that codepen, and have the onBlur commented out. Try refreshing the page and 1.) unfocus the input by clicking anywhere on the page 2.) press the toggle focus button. The input should become focused again, but takes two clicks of the button to focus.

Comment: @DanZuzevich I still think Mohammad is onto something here. Clearly: clicking the button will blur the field through normal DOM operation, regardless of what React does. So, even if it's not an infinite loop, you've got a case where two conflicting updates will fire: the field's blur will fire, and then the click will fire. I think this is not a true race condition, but it's close.

Comment: I know what you are saying about the unnecessary setFocus invocation. If you look at the useEffect call, on initial mount it will call focus, and trigger the onFocus function which sets focused = true. Which is unnecessary, because it already is true. So yeah, I think that's the same thing going on with the onBlur function?

Comment: NASA can send robots to Mars, and I can't figure out how to focus/blur my form properly. Ugh.

Comment: I think it's more than merely "unnecessary" -- I think it's the cause of the bug. I can see why Mohammad's fix isn't precisely what you want, but I think he's nailed the cause of the problem. The scenario you need to carefully debug is: field has focus and user clicks button.

Comment: My best guess is it's a race condition issue. I can't prove it but i can offer an alternative solution where we will try to set the state after 300ms delay. Which also solves the issue. Check my updated answer

Comment: Alright, thanks guys. I am taking a lunch break now, but will come back to this answer and check it out. I'll upvote if it seems like a good solution. Thank you!